# Docker image per branch is inefficient

Tags: docker, testing, continuous-integration

I have a web application that has recently been moved to using Docker. In the past I deployed every branch that is pushed to the BitBucket repository to IIS using web deploy. Each branch would be it's own application, so that testing is easy.

Now that I have moved to using Docker, is there an efficient way to continue deploying the application per branch? I know I can create an image for each branch and deploy those images, but I end up using up a decent amount of space.

Comment: Why create an image for every branch? You can create a base image and then map your branch to inside of container.

Comment: Creating an image per build seems to be the standard CI/CD pattern.  And then you can name the branch in the image tag in your `docker run` command / Docker Compose YAML file / Kubernetes Deployment description.  You wouldn't want to separately ship your code to your deployment system to mount it on top of the output from your build system.